# Using Spring RequestContextListener

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

If I use

```
@Autowired HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;
```

I get an error:

> No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes
>   outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of
>   the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within
>   a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably
>   running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case,
>   use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the
>   current request.

Then on googling I'm asked to use:

```
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
```

I am able to get the IP address from the request. My query is if am using this inside a Async method will the IP address be correct when there are multiple requests coming in parallel.

It's a spring mvc application. Is there a better method to get the IP address. I want to log the IP address in my custom provider.

Comment: Inside @Async, you won't get the IP address using the `RequestContextListener`. If you are calling a service @Async method, you can pass the IP inside parameter to the method.The method to get the IP is correct for other scenarios, but for @Async it will not work as far as I know.

Answer (score -1):

I think that You use it in a wrong way.
You can get `HttpServletRequest` in controller method invocation.

```
@RestController
public class SomeController {

   @RequestMapping(path = "/dosmtng")
   public void doSomething(HttpServletRequest request, <other params>){
      ....
   }

}
```

Like this,  for example.
So You cal get necessary attributes from request here and put them in other method.